# Cannot create directory with sysoper

Tags: oracle

My user has the two roles sysdba and sysoper. When I connect as sysdba I can sucessfully perform in sql plus:

```
@> connect myuser/mypassword@myservice as sysdba;
Connected.
SYS@service> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DP_TMP_5714 AS '/path/to/dir';

Directory created.
```

However, when I open session as sysoper It performs as follows:

```
@> connect myuser/mypassword@myservice as sysoper;
Connected.
SYS@service> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DP_TMP_5714 AS '/path/to/dir';
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DP_TMP_5714 AS '/path/to/dir';
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

I already run the grant command:

```
GRANT CREATE ANY DIRECTORY TO myuser
```

Answer (score 2):

Great! Your database is working precisely as it should!

SYSDBA has the power to do just about anything to the database, including creating objects, dropping objects, etc, blah.

SYSOPER has a reduced set of privileges which allow such users to perform basic operational tasks but not to look at user data.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dba.htm#ADMIN11047